# How do you tell Craft to change post directions from row-to-row?

Tags: templating

I have a grid.  The pattern is:

- `**Row 1**` = `1 x featured post` and `2 x vertical posts`.  (The feature is the equivalent of 2 vertical posts.)
- `**Row 2**` = `2 x horizontal posts`  `Row 2` starts with the `4th most recent post`.
- `**Row 3**` = `4 x vertical posts`
- `**Rows 4-n**` repeat `Row 2` and `Row 3`...

I have experimented with `{% if loop.index is divisible by(2) %}stuff{% else %}other-stuff{% endif %}` to switch between the horizontal and vertical alignments.

So, this is a 2 part question.

1. How do I pull the 2nd and 3rd most recent posts to populate the 2 vertical posts in `Row 1`?

I am already calling the `featured post` using `{% for post in craft.entries.section('posts') %}{% if loop.first and craft.request.pageNum == 1 %}`...

2. Next, how do I then tell Craft to populate 2 horizontals in `Row 2` and then switch to 4 verticals in `Row 3`?   I assume its best to separate step #1 from step #2 which would require `Row 2` to start with `4th most recent post`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do multiple "for" loops on the first craft.entries request using limits and offsets:

```
{% set posts = craft.entries.section('posts') %}

{# ROW ONE #}
{% for post in posts.limit(1) %}
   html stuff for first post
{% endfor %}

{% for post in posts.limit(2).offset(1) %}
   html stuff for 2nd and 3rd posts skipping 1
{% endfor %}

{# ROW TWO #}
{% for post in posts.limit(2).offset(3) %}
   html stuff for 4th and 5th posts skipping 3
{% endfor %}
```

etc.

For the switching back and forth between horizontal and vertical, you can set up a couple of macros and call them where needed(or includes for that matter, lots of ways to skin this cat).

```
{% macro vertical(url, title) %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ url }}" title="{{ title }}">{{ title }}</a>
</li>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro horizontal(url, title) %}{# different html #}
<div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <a href="{{ url }}">Learn More</a>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

and then where you need them in the first part of your question above:

```
{% for post in posts.limit(2).offset(3) %}
   {{ _self.vertical(post.url, post.title) }}
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for post in posts.limit(2).offset(3) %}
   {{ _self.horizontal(post.url, post.title) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Twig Macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)

[Using Macros by Mijingo](https://mijingo.com/blog/using-macros-in-twig-and-craft)

alternatively with includes

```
{% for post in posts.limit(2).offset(1) %}
  {% include "_includes/vertical_layout" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Bingo.  I used includes with no issues.  Macros are still a bit intimidating (for now at least).